# why option select reactive form angular not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm building reactive form with angular 5, I'm trying to add select with option from list, but the list not present in the html page.
I saw some similar questions and tried the suggested answers but without succsses, what am i doing wrong?

ts:

```
firstQuestionnaire: FormGroup;
yearsCurrentHome: string [] = ['1','2','3','4','5+'];
default: string = '1';

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.firstQuestionnaire=this.createFormGroup();
    this.firstQuestionnaire.controls['yearsInCurrentHome'].setValue(this.default, {onlySelf: true});
  }
createFormGroup() {
    return new FormGroup({
      yearsInCurrentHome: new FormControl(null)
 });
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="question">
      <label>YEARS: </label>
      <select formControlName="yearsInCurrentHome">
        <option *ngFor="let year of yearsCurrentHome" [ngValue]="year"> {{year}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple issues with your implementation. You might want to do the following:

1. Add `ReactiveFormsModule` to the `imports` array of your `@NgModule` if not already added.
2. Specify the `form` tag with `[formGroup]` on it if not done already.
3. Check for errors on the console.
4. Try comparing your implementation with the implementation in [**this Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pna9av?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) ref.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include form tag in your html   as below :

```
 <form [formGroup]="firstQuestionnaire">
        <select formControlName="yearsInCurrentHome">
            <option *ngFor="let year of yearsCurrentHome" [ngValue]="year"> {{year}}
            </option>
          </select>
    </form>
```